# How do I calculate the probability of these two events?

Tags: probability, statistics

Two members of a club are chosen at random for a photograph. [The table here shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmylJ.png) the data that I have.

My question is how do I **find the probability that exactly one of the members is female and exactly one is a child**.

Also, are these independent probabilities or not? From what I understand, independent probabilities are those that don't effect each other. Since if you pick a person, the probability for the second person will change. Am I right when I say that these are dependant probabilities? Do I have the right reasoning for this?

Comment: "The exact probability" is an overstatement. It sounds like you're estimating from data so you can get the best guess from that although the exact probability doesn't come into this.

Comment: okay, changed the question. How do I solve this question now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 possibilities. Either one is a female and the other is a child or one is a female child and the other is an adult male.

We don't mind the order so we can also mutliply that by 2.

P(one female adult & other male child) = $\frac{4}{25}.\frac{5}{24}$ = $\frac{4}{120}$.

P(one female child & other neither) = $\frac{10}{25}.\frac{6}{24}$= $\frac{18}{120}$.

Adding together and multiplying by 2 we get $\frac{44}{120}$ = $\frac{11}{30}$.

Yes, they are dependent probabilities for the reasons you say. Taking the first example here, the first event has probability 4/25 but this removes someone from the pool. So the next becomes 5/24. If the first event was the 5/25 one then the next would be 4/24 but since these are multiplied we can just multiply by 2 for the order change. Hope this help.

Comment: shouldn't the probability of one female child and other be 60/600= 1/10, not 18/120?